# Regular Expression works for all but 1.00 in Splunk rex

Tags: regex, currency, splunk, money-format

I am use a rex in splunk to extract the decimal amount from a field that contains the amount plus the 3-digit currency code. Both values are separated by a space.

Examples:

```
200.00 INR
2390.11 INR
1.00 INR
1789.00 INR
```

I am using the rex command inline:

```
rex field=TxnAmt "(?<TxnAmt>[^\s]\d+.\d+)
```

Using this command is mostly successful, but where my error comes into play is with the 1.00 INR.

Results:

```
200.00
2390.11
1.00 INR
1789.00
```

Any ideas would be helpful. Full Disclaimer: I am not a full programmer, nor do I aspire to be, but I do enjoy writing Regexs on Splunk.

Comment: sidenote: I think you should escape `.` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your current regex, try changing `[^\s]\d+.\d+` to the following:

```
\d+\.\d+
```

Your current regex does not escape the `.`, so the `.` in your regex will actually match any character.  I'm not really sure what you are trying to do with `[^\s]`, since this will match a single non-whitespace character, and it looks like you are only interested in the digits.

Your current regex fails on "1.00 INR" because the `1` is matched by `[^\s]`, and then your regex looks for one or more digits but the next character is a `.`.

Comment: Thanks. That worked beautifully. I guess I am so used to reading until a point when parsing comma separated values I didn't think to leave it out.

Comment: No problem, and welcome to the site!  If my answer worked you can [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the outline of the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know about rex, but if it's just a plain ole regex you need, this would work:

```
\d+\.\d+(?= [a-zA-Z]{3})
```

1 or more digits, followed by a decimal, followed by 1 or more digits, and making sure it has a space and 3 letters following it.

Comment: Splunk uses PCRE. rex is just an inline regex on a field. [link](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/rex) Thank you though for this. I need to extract the currency out separately and might be able to use this.